# jQuery AJAX Question

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery and running this Javascript:

```
$.ajax ({
    url: 'http://1.1.1.1/cgi-bin/script.cgi?scm:scm/data/system_names',
    context: $("#elem"),
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (data) {
        $xmlDoc = parseXML (data);
        $(this).html ($xmlDoc.find ("elem").text ());
    }
});
```

When the requests runs, I can see that this URL is requested:

```
http://1.1.1.1/cgi-bin/script.cgi?scm:scm/data/system_names&_=1306868212809
```

How can I get rid of the `&_=1306868212809` part? It's messing with my request. I have no control over the CGI script, so I have to do it the way you see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `cache` parameter:

```
cache: true
```

Comment: That got rid of the parameter, but I cannot be caching my requests. The data returned will change every second.

Comment: @Nik, don't forget that you are using cross domain AJAX request which is implemented by including a `<script>` tag. This of course means that you are only limited to GET requests and this of course means that they are cached by client browsers. So it's up to you to choose. Either you don't include `cache: true` and you get fresh content (assuming that the only way to achieve this is to append a random query string parameter) or you include it but suffer the consequences. POST requests are not cached but obviously you cannot use a POST request with cross domain.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `cache` key to `true`

```
$.ajax ({
  url: 'http://1.1.1.1/cgi-bin/script.cgi?scm:scm/data/system_names',
  context: $("#elem"),
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: "xml",
  cache: true,
  success: function (data) {
    $xmlDoc = parseXML (data);
    $(this).html ($xmlDoc.find ("elem").text ());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be wrapping the URL in string quotes?

```
$.ajax ({
    url: 'http://1.1.1.1/cgi-bin/script.cgi?scm:scm/data/system_names',
    context: $("#elem"),
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (data) {
        $xmlDoc = parseXML (data);
        $(this).html ($xmlDoc.find ("elem").text ());
    }
});
```

From their documentation - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

The `Url` property should be a `string`.

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part. It is enclosed in quotes.